# Image tiling on Android, garbage collector slows down

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I'm implementing an application that requires lots of big images, with zooming, paging using viewPager and all that stuff.

Using the whole image is not an option, because it will give an OutOfMemory exception, so I'm implementing a custom tiling system. I already have the image cut in several pieces on the sdcard, and 3 versions of them, low, medium, and high quality.

The idea is to load the right tiles depending on the zoom.

All beautiful in theory, and this system is already working nicely on our iOS app, but on Android, it becomes unbearably slow because of the garbage collector.

Somehow, it seems that it takes too long to the garbage collector to free the memory of the bitmaps, and my application tries to create new bitmaps before the GC cleared the ones i asked him to clear, so, if the user paginate too fast, memory will grow and at some point all the app will became slow and eventually it will crash on OOM.

Every time the user goes to the next page, I call the following on the old bitmaps:

lowResBitmap.recycle();
lowResBitmap = null;

Is there a better way to handle Bitmap allocation and deallocation on Android?

EDIT: I forget to call .recycle() on some bitmaps, now it isn't crashing on OOM anymore, but it's very slow (comparing to our iOS app), because every time the user turns the page, Android calls GC many times, and it slows down my drawing thread.

Comment: Are you sure the slowness is because of the GC? I suspect you might be wrong about that... do some performance analysis to find out where the bottlenecks really are. For what it's worth I've done similar tile-based apps (a tile being a 256x256 .png) using openGL rendering and it ran as smooth as anything on iOS. How are you drawing the screen? How many threads do you have? Show some code and I can probably help better...

Comment: Here is the strange thing, I disabled the High res tiles for testing, and when the user turns the page, I call bitmap.recycle() and bitmap = null on the only bitmap the page has, the lowRes version. But, looking at DDMS, I see lot's of GC_FOR_ALLOC and GC_CONCURRENT, even if I'm dealing with only one bitmap. Well, I have a lot of control variables, but they are all small strings containing some paths, I don't believe they should be causing a GC

Comment: One more thing, I'm using a ViewPager for pagination

Comment: Reuben, I was thinking in using openGL rendering too, but I got performance problems using SurfaceView, as my View is inside a ViewPager, so I think I'm stuck with using a CustomView overriding the Draw method, unless I remove ViewPager and do all pagination control manually right?

Comment: When do you decode Bitmaps? What dimensions are they?

Comment: The lowerRes bitmaps are very fast to load, so I put on the initialization of the view. The higher res, are being loaded on a separate worker thread, part by part, using a tiling mechanism.

Comment: I still recommend you do some performance analysis to see where the bottlenecks really are. It's usually a surprising and revealing exercise.  Btw, to help keep your Ui thread 100% responsive suggest you run worker threads at a lower priority than the default.

Comment: Sure, I will do that. I don't have much experience in fine performance tuning, but I'm guessing I should learn to use Traceview right?

Comment: Exactly. It's pretty simple. Tim Bray wrote a simple tutorial at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/10/traceview-war-story.html.

Comment: Ok, you won, I found a *huge* performance killer on a part of the code that was called every time the user changed the page. I'm getting a much better performance now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you call recycle or not on your Bitmap or not should not make any difference as long as the variable lowResBitmap is the only reference to the Bitmap instance.

From the [Android SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29):

> This (recycle) is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the
>   normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more
>   references to this bitmap.

Have you tested to call `System.gc();` directly for advising the garbage collector to do the at a specific time?

**Update (works unfortuanetly only with API11+ / Android 3:**

May be you can prevent the GC completely by re-using existing Bitmaps when loading new tiles. I assume that all of your tiles are of the same size therefore this approach would be ideally. From what I understood this can be done by using [inBitmap of BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap).

Comment: oh, lowResBitmap is just an example on how I deallocate. I have a HashMap holding the tile bitmaps, and I iterate on that hashmap clearing them

Comment: Also, I call System.gc() when I'm with low memory

Comment: What don't understand is why the GC has so much to do. The required collecting time depends mostly on the number of objects. "Large" memory blocks like they are used by images should be easy to collect. May be also memory fragmentation is a problem? BTW: See my updated answer.

Comment: Hey, this bitmap reuse is very cool! Unfortunately I have to suport 2.2, so I can't use right now. But in near future I need a strategy to maintain two versions, one using level 8 and other one using level 11, so I can use things like this. Thanks!